# Regex: Comma separated values restricted to 8 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a regex to match comma-separated values restricted to 8 characters or less.

The comma-separated values can only have numbers.

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to apply regex on an input field. where `1 >= digits <= 8` only **numeric** are allowed.

and if a user wants to add multiple values they must be comma (,) separated.

Eg:
`1148927,1216814,1212327,1213381,1213274,1211982,1149123,1149628` - Valid as every value is < 8 
`7,14,227,2181,13274,211982,1149123,10149628` - Valid as every value has 1 to 8 digits 
`1148927,1216814,121212122123359,1212327,1213381,1213274,1211982,1149123,1149628` - Invalid

so far I am able to achieve this

`/^[0-9]{8}(?:,[0-9]{8})*$/gm`

The problem with this is `{8} matches the previous token exactly 8 times` but I want it to match anywhere till 8.

I know I am pretty close, not able to get that final regex.

Comment: You can give a range like `{1,8}` which means between 1 and 8 characters

Comment: `/^\d{1,8}(?:,\d{1,8})*$/gm` would allow for a comma-separated list of 1 to 8 digits.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `{8}` which requires exactly 8 matches. You should use something like `{1,8}`:

```
/^[0-9]{1,8}(?:,[0-9]{1,8})*$/gm
```

And if you want to allow an optional trailing comma:

```
/^[0-9]{1,8}(?:,[0-9]{1,8})*,?$/gm
```

Comment: Oh Okay! This works well. Silly one! 

Though this allows only `7,14,227,21213281,13274` but fails at `7,14,227,21213281,13274,`. means a comma in the end. This should also allow.

Comment: @shivamdixit Allowing a comma at the end is as simple as adding `,?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use range `{min, max}`

```
/^[0-9]{1,8}(?:,[0-9]{1,8})*$/gm
```